# How to make JavaFX wait for a node to finish config before running the next line of code

Tags: java, javafx

I have to do a complicated process for loading images which takes various amounts of time and while this process is running I want to inform the user that a process is in fact running in the background.
For that i've already given up on something animated because it'd have to **actually** be in the background on a different thread so all i want is a big red text that says something like "loading... please wait".
Simplified example:
Main:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    StackPane mainPane;

    Text text;

    public void initialize(){
        text = new Text();
        text.setText("please wait");
        text.setVisible(false);
        mainPane.getChildren().add(text);

    }

    public void handleMouseClick(){
        text.setVisible(true);
        longProcess();
        text.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void longProcess(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Fxml file:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<StackPane fx:controller="sample.Controller"
           xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
           fx:id="mainPane"
           onMouseClicked="#handleMouseClick">
</StackPane>
```

So this code creates a simple stackpane and adds an invisible text to it and then on mouse click it should first show the text then make the thread sleep (resembling my long process) then make the text invisible again but it just makes the thread sleep and doesn't show the text for some reason.

Comment: If these tasks can take a while, you really should be executing on a separate thread either way and then reporting back to the UI when it's finished... There are several ways this can be done that prevents the UI from being used without actually blocking it and making it appear frozen.

Comment: @kleopatra The code above demonstrates the problem as the `handleKeyPressed` method gets called after key press and it should first set the `loadingText` visible but instead the main FX thread freezes due to the `PictureRenderer.inputHandler` method call which is why I'm asking how to make sure the `setVisible` method gets done before the  `PictureRenderer.inputHandler` method gets called.

Comment: @Zephyr So the problem is with the `inputHandler` method as it makes changes to the active nodes so i tried putting it to a different thread but then it throws an error for not working on the main FX thread and I don't really want to seperate the node operations to avoid that. That's why i'm looking for a simple solution for this exact thing.

Comment: if you really want help, you _must_ provide the example as suggested by the help page - and no, a snippet out off context doesn't demonstrate anything, as your comment to @Zephyr implies ;) Voted to close ..

Comment: Look into `Platform.runLater()`

Comment: There.. simplified it. But a simple putting the `longProcess()` into a runnable and the using Platform.runLater doesn`t help.

Comment: basically, you must move the longProcess into a background thread and update the ui in a platform.runlater. Look into the fx Task (or worker) class: let the background task run, listen to any of its notifications that related to being finished and reset the textField's visibility inside that listener

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted to avoid with some super cheeky way because, as I said the program is not built for this so I'd have to rewrite a lot of code to be able to do this. Thanks for the help anyway, even though i just started on this page and you were kind of rude about how i don't really know how i should be posting things.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

Since kleopatra pointed out that the old snippet would not work, I have searched how to do that and found this answer:

> *"The following code will pause and change the value in a label (full disclosure, I'm reusing code I wrote for another question):"*
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454506/10971694

**Old:**

Will the code below help?

```
while(!node.isVisible()){
   System.out.println("waiting...");
   try {
       Thread.sleep(delay);
   } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: if that snippets amounts to  sleeping on the fx application thread then it's wrong

Comment: @kleopatra would you check the link in the edited one?

Answer (score 0):

Change your handleMouseClickMethod to look like this and it should work

```
public void handleMouseClick(){
    int delayTime = 10;//Set this to whatever you want your delay in Seconds
    Label text = new Label("please wait");
    mainPane.getChildren().add(text);
    final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(()->
            Platform.runLater(()->mainPane.getChildren().remove(text)), delayTime, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```