# Looping Threads every 3 seconds in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, javafx

I'm currently working on a stock market application that changes the values of the prices of the stocks every so often (for this example, let's have the stocks change value every 3 seconds). I looked into doing *tasks* but I couldn't find a way to make the tasks run continuously. Is there a way to make a *task* loop every 3 seconds within the main class? *(To clarify, I would like this looped task to be added into the body of my main method, without using external classes besides the main method)*

Here's what I have so far:

```
Task<Void> change = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {}
                return null;
            }
        };
        change.setOnSucceeded(new EventHandler<WorkerStateEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(WorkerStateEvent event) {

            }
        });
        new Thread(change).start();
```

NOTE: This code was referenced from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26454506/12712327)

Comment: What about using a [`ScheduledService`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/concurrent/ScheduledService.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not think in terms of “continuously” or “looping”. Instead think of the job to be done (look up fresh stock prices), and how often do you want that task to be performed.

For the first part, your task, define a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) (or `Callable`). That means simply having a `run` method to comply with the contract of the interface.

In lambda syntax:

```
Runnable runnable =
    () -> { 
        System.out.println( "Looking up fresh stock prices at " + Instant.now().toString() ) ; 
    } 
;
```

Next, study up on the Executors framework built into modern Java. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html). This framework greatly simplifies the tricky work of scheduling work on threads.

Specifically, you want to use [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). This interface is for scheduling a task to run once at a specific time (actually, run once after a specific delay expires), *or* run a task repeatedly. You, of course, want the latter.

Get an implementation from the [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class. For your needs, we need only a single-thread. In other cases, you may want to use a thread pool.

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
```

You have a choice two variations for scheduling: [`scheduleAtFixedRate​`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) and [`scheduleWithFixedDelay​`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,long,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)). Study them both to decide which is best for your case. In either case, know that you cannot rely on the scheduling perfectly. Your host OS controls granting access to the CPU cores to the JVM, and the JVM may be juggling a multitude of threads. So the timing may be delayed sporadically, though for most business apps the delays should be insignificant.

```
ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( runnable , 0L , 3L , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

You may want to capture the returned [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object to monitor progress or completion. Our line of code above ignores it.

**IMPORTANT** Be sure to gracefully shutdown your executor service when no longer needed, or when your app is being shut down. Otherwise your threads may continue running in the background, surviving your app's exit.

**IMPORTANT** Wrap the task inside your `Runnable` task with a try-catch. Any exception or error thrown that bubbles up to the level of the Runnable object will result in your executor service silently terminating. No further calls will be scheduled. Search Stack Overflow to learn more.

```
Runnable runnable =
        ( ) -> {
            try
            {
                System.out.println( "Looking up fresh stock prices at " + Instant.now().toString() );
            }
            catch ( Exception e )
            {
                // … try to recover, if you want the scheduled executor service to continue scheduling this task.
                // Or, at least, do logging/notifications to know when and why the scheduling of this task halted.
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
```

**IMPORTANT** *Never* access/modify any user-interface widget from a background thread when using UI frameworks like [*JavaFX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), [*Swing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)), or [*Vaadin*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaadin). Each UI framework will provide its own mechanism by which you can schedule widget-updating work to be performed **on the UI’s thread**. I am not familiar with JavaFX, so I cannot be more specific.

Put all that together in this example code. And, for those not comfortable with lambda syntax, use an anonymous class for our `Runnable`.

```
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Bogus
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        Runnable runnable =
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ( )
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            System.out.println( "Looking up fresh stock prices at " + Instant.now().toString() );
                        }
                        catch ( Exception e )
                        {
                            // … try to recover, if you want the scheduled executor service to continue scheduling this task.
                            // Or, at least, do logging/notifications to know when and why the scheduling of this task halted.
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                };

        ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

        ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( runnable , 0L , 3L , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep( TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis( 1 ) );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            ses.shutdown();  // IMPORTANT Always shutdown gracefully your executor service so the thread pool does not outlive your app.
        }

        System.out.println( "INFO - Completed run at: " + Instant.now() );
    }
}
```

When run.

> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:35:35.987199Z
>
> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:35:39.026132Z
>
> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:35:42.030302Z
>
> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:35:45.035176Z
>
> …
>
> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:36:30.097743Z
>
> Looking up fresh stock prices at 2020-02-15T06:36:33.100713Z
>
> INFO - Completed run at: 2020-02-15T06:36:35.988752Z

As mentioned above, notice how the tasks are not *exactly* three seconds apart, but are pretty close. This example was run on a Mac mini with 6 real cores and no hyper-threading, 32 gigs of memory, on macOS Mojave, with Java 13.

Comment: There's also JavaFX-specific utilities for scheduled, periodic background tasks (see [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236314/looping-threads-every-3-seconds-in-javafx#comment106547498_60236314)).

Comment: @Basil I appreciate the very detailed response! One quick question, when I put this code into my main method, the program doesn't open my main window, it only does what is within the lambda expression (I'm new to lambda expressions my apologies). Am I putting this into my program correctly by just putting it into my main method, then using ses.scheduleWithFixedDelay( runnable , 0L , 3L , TimeUnit.SECONDS ); to call the function? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @KellenMiller The code [runs in IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/pAoqLI) though it times out, going past limits set by IdeOne.com. And I replaced the code in the Answer to (a) replace the lambda with an anonymous class syntax, and (b) include an entire class that works, copy-pasted whole.